# Destiny Vanguard Armory only level 5 and 20?

Tags: destiny

Will the Vanguard Armory ever get any content except level 5 or 20 items?

Meaning, for instance when I get to level 10, will the level 5 items be replaced with level 10 items?

Or will I only have available the level 5 items until I reach level 20 and can buy the level 20 items?

Right now it has 6 items at level 5, under "Vanguard Armory", and 12 items under "Vanguard Weapons", all at level 20.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Vanguard Armory vendor will feature the following item levels:

1. Player levels 1-9: Level 5 gear purchasable for glimmer
2. Player levels 10-20: Level 10 gear purchasable for glimmer

Additionally the vendor will feature legendary level 20 gear that can be purchased if you have the requisite Vanguard reputation, and the Vanguard marks to spend. These items are present regardless of player level.

So, to conclude. You can buy level 5 items, level 10 items, and level 20 items.

Comment: chest and head pieces require commendations, which can be obtained from level Vanguard Rep past 3.  All weapons do require Vanguard Commendations.

Answer (score 0):

The Vanguard items below level 10 are from pre-order bonuses.  They will scale up to level 10 (debated, maybe higher) every time the shop refreshes (every 3 hours I believe). [Source](http://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/2fz0lh/psa_that_vanguard_gear_access_you_get_with_the/)

The level 20 gear is Vanguard gear I believe:

> Vanguard Marks: You’ll unlock Vanguard Marks at level 18 and it can be used to buy high-end gear for your character. It’s awarded for completing high level strikes as well as participating in weekly activities, as well as exchanging items with the Vanguard Quartermaster.
>
> Vanguard Reputation: this is awarded for completing Vanguard Bounties and can be used to buy high level gear.

[Source](http://www.vg247.com/2014/09/10/destiny-guide-tower-factions-vanguard-crucible-reputation-and-marks/)